# nRF24L01 module using Mirf library was working and then stopped

Tags: arduino-uno, c++, nrf24l01+

I have two nRF24L01 modules, they are both attached to a sensor shield that has special ports for this type of module, on Arduino Unos.

[image: Sensor shield, with nRF24LO1 in it]

I have this code on the Arduino that is sending the signal:

```C++
#include <MirfHardwareSpiDriver.h>
#include <MirfSpiDriver.h>
#include <Mirf.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Wire.h>

//0 = stop, 1 = left, 2 = right, 3 = forward, 4 = backwards
long command;
long last_command;

long Joystick_1_X;
long Joystick_1_Y;
long Joystick_1;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Mirf.spi = &MirfHardwareSpi;  
  Mirf.init(); 
  Mirf.setTADDR((byte *)"serv1");
  Mirf.payload = sizeof(long);
  Mirf.config(); 
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  Joystick_1_X = analogRead(A0);
  Joystick_1_Y = analogRead(A1);

  if(Joystick_1_X < 450){
     command = 1;
  }else if(Joystick_1_X > 600){
    command = 2;
  }else if(Joystick_1_Y > 600){
    command = 3;
  }else if(Joystick_1_Y < 400){
    command = 4;
  }else{
    command = 0;
  }
  if(command == last_command){
  }else{
    Mirf.send((byte *)&command);
    last_command = command;
   }
  }
```

and this code on the Arduino that is receiving

```C++
#include "SPI.h"
#include "Mirf.h"
#include "nRF24L01.h"
#include "MirfHardwareSpiDriver.h"

int TN1= 3;
int TN2 = 4;
int ENA = 9;

int TN4 = 5;
int TN3 = 6;
int ENB = 10;

long data;

void setup() {
 pinMode(TN1, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(TN2, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(TN3, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(TN4, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(ENA, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(ENB, OUTPUT);

 Mirf.spi = &MirfHardwareSpi;
 Mirf.init();
 Mirf.setRADDR((byte *)"serv1");
 Mirf.payload = sizeof(long);
 Mirf.config();
 Serial.begin(115200);
 Serial.print("begin");

}

void loop() {

  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  receiveCommand();
  if(data == 1){
    left();
  }else if(data == 2){
    right();
  }else if(data == 3){
    forward();
  }else if(data == 4){
    backwards();
  }else if(data == 0){
    stop_rover();
  }
}

void receiveCommand(){
  if(!Mirf.isSending() && Mirf.dataReady()){
    Mirf.getData((byte *)&data);
    Mirf.rxFifoEmpty();
    Serial.print(data);
  }else{
    Serial.println("No data to be recieved");
  }
}

void forward(){
  digitalWrite(ENB, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(ENA, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(TN4, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(TN3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(TN1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(TN2, LOW);
}

void backwards(){
  digitalWrite(ENB, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(ENA, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(TN4, LOW);
  digitalWrite(TN3, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(TN1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(TN2, HIGH);
}

void left(){
   digitalWrite(ENA, HIGH);
   digitalWrite(TN1, HIGH);
   digitalWrite(TN2, LOW);
}

void right(){
  digitalWrite(ENB, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(TN4, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(TN3, LOW);
}

void stop_rover(){
  digitalWrite(ENB, LOW);
  digitalWrite(ENA, LOW);
  digitalWrite(TN4, LOW);
  digitalWrite(TN3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(TN1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(TN2, LOW);
}
```

This was working, and the rover did spin its wheels when the remote broadcasted a signal, but then it just stopped. The sensor shield says that they are plugged into the 3V port, I tried using the RF24 library and that did not work either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you please try the builtin self test checks that come with RF24 library maintained by TMRh20? Do they all work properly?

Comment: I uploaded the GettingStarted.ino file to two Arduinos the trasmitting node printed out this Now sending
Sent 18204112, Got response 0, Round-trip delay 18204112 microseconds
Now sending
Sent 28434792, Got response 0, Round-trip delay 28434792 microseconds
and the receiving node printed out this Sent response 251854848
Sent response 0

Comment: Something is wrong. Check your wiring and if you can, solder electrolytic caps to the GND and 3.3V pins of the radio module.

Comment: There is no wiring the nRF24L01 is plugged into a sensor which is on the arduino, I put a picture of the sensor shield with the nRF24L01 above.

Comment: Are the defined pins in the sketch right? Could you please solder a cap to the power pins of the radio module?

Comment: I tried changing the defined pins to something else but I keep getting Now sending
failed
Sent 3496020, Got response 0, Round-trip delay 3496020 microseconds. And i do not have any caps

Comment: What does the other node say? Also, please go buy some capacitors and solder them on, it can solve your problem.

Comment: I soldered on capacitors, but I am still getting Sent 28434792, Got response 0,

Comment: What does the second node say? Have you checked if your CS and CE pins are defined correctly?

Comment: The receiving node is writing Sent response 1795, Sent response 0, Sent response 259, Sent response 0 and when I swaped around the defined CS and CE pins the node wrote Now sending
failed
Failed, response timed out.

Comment: Try the example named Transfer. The round trip delay and sent responses are weird although the pins are right and you have soldered capacitors on the NRF24L01+ modules. Weird.

Comment: I do not think that that worked, the receiving node wrote this Rate: 365.92
Payload Count: 11435
Rate: 16.54
Payload Count: 517
Rate: 0.00
Payload Count: 0
Rate: 0.00
Payload Count: 0
Rate: 0.00
Payload Count: 0
Rate: 0.00 and the transfering node wrote this Initiating Basic Data Transfer

Transfer complete at 219.18 KB/s
0 of 10000 Packets Failed to Send
Initiating Basic Data Transfer

Transfer complete at 219.18 KB/s
0 of 10000 Packets Failed to Send

Comment: Also they both wrote at the start this also at the start they both said this STATUS   = 0x00 RX_DR=0 TX_DS=0 MAX_RT=0 RX_P_NO=0 TX_FULL=0
RX_ADDR_P0-1  = 0x0000000000 0x0000000000
RX_ADDR_P2-5  = 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
TX_ADDR   = 0x0000000000
RX_PW_P0-6  = 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
EN_AA   = 0x00
EN_RXADDR  = 0x00
RF_CH   = 0x00
RF_SETUP  = 0x00
CONFIG   = 0x00
DYNPD/FEATURE  = 0x00 0x00
Data Rate  = 1MBPS
Model   = nRF24L01
CRC Length  = Disabled
PA Power  = PA_MIN

Comment: If it is true that you have defined the CS and CE pins right, your nrf24l01+ modules are broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the MIRF Library that I got from [here](http://www.sainsmart.com/zen/documents/20-011-401/Codes_for_Self-balancing_robot.zip), and then using this code to send

```
 Mirf.send((byte *)&command);
    while(Mirf.isSending()){
        }
```

and this code to receive

```
 if(!Mirf.isSending() && Mirf.dataReady()){
    Mirf.getData((byte *)&data);
    Mirf.rxFifoEmpty();
else(){
}
```

I was able to get it to work